# Properties file for different OS

Tags: java, properties

I am working on a java project. I have a properties file that includes some file paths and locations. Is there a way to add a condition to the properties file and choose which path to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to do this with a properties file is to have all the versions of the property in the file, and have the logic to choose them in the actual Java code.  For example, if you want different property values per operating system, you might have something like

```
file.limit.windows = 500
file.limit.mac = 1000
file.limit.linux = 2000
```

And then have Java code that does something like

```
properties.getProperty("file.limit." + operatingSystemName);
```